# How do I view an image in Spyder's Variable Explorer?

Tags: spyder

I would like to view image variables (NxNx3 in my case) as images in Spyder. I have seen this done before, but I don't currently have the option to view them in this way.

My question is, how do I view images (numpy arrays etc) as images from the Variable Explorer?

[image: Here are the options I have in the context menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) We don't support the functionality to display images for multidimensional arrays. Only 2D and 1D arrays are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the "Show Image" option when you right click on the image variable. It shows the picture in the "plots" tab. Hope this helps.

[image: screenshot]